# InnoDB on MySQL 5.6 with OSX/CE1.7

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, mysql, setup

I am getting this error

```
Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.
```

with MySQL 5.6 on my MAC OSX Maverick

```
mysql> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO
```

Comment: It would be great is anyone has a better answer for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way of doing this by adding a rewrite rather than changing the core code. [Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870033/2054777)

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_InstallBugfix>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_InstallBugfix>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <installbugfix>
                <class>Company_InstallBugfix_Model</class>
            </installbugfix>
            <install>
                <rewrite>
                    <installer_db_mysql4>Company_InstallBugfix_Model_Installer_Db_Mysql4</installer_db_mysql4>
                </rewrite>
            </install>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

File Company_InstallBugfix_Model_Installer_Db_Mysql4

```
<?php
class Company_InstallBugfix_Model_Installer_Db_Mysql4 extends Mage_Install_Model_Installer_Db_Mysql4
{
    /**
     * Check InnoDB support
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportEngine()
    {
        $supportsEngine = parent::supportEngine();
        if ($supportsEngine) {
            return true;
        }
        $variables = $this
                     ->_getConnection()
                     ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
        return (isset($variables['InnoDB']) && $variables['InnoDB'] != 'NO');
    }
}
```

Also this issue was fixed in Magento version 1.8 where the function looks as follows:

```
/**
 * Check InnoDB support
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function supportEngine()
{
    $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
        ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
    return isset($variables['InnoDB']) && ($variables['InnoDB'] == 'DEFAULT' || $variables['InnoDB'] == 'YES');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am sure there is a better answer than this

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php
index bc482b5..ce55834 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php
@@ -60,6 +60,10 @@ class Mage_Install_Model_Installer_Db_Mysql4 extends Mage_Install_Model_Installe
     {
         $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
             ->fetchPairs('SHOW VARIABLES');
+        if (substr($variables['version'], 0, 3) == '5.6') {
+            return true;
+        } else {
             return (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') ? false : true;
         }
+    }
 }
```

The above worked